# UTF16 hex to text

Tags: postgresql, utf-16

I have UTF-16 hex representation such as  “0633064406270645” which is "سلام" in Arabic language.

I would like to convert it to its text equivalent. Is there a straight way to do that in PostgreSQL?

I can convert the UTF code point like below; unfortunately it seems UTF16 is not supported. Any ideas on how to do it in PostgreSQL, worst case I will write a function?

```
SELECT convert_from (decode (E'D8B3D984D8A7D985', 'hex'),'UTF8');

"سلام"

SELECT convert_from (decode (E'0633064406270645', 'hex'),'UTF16');

ERROR:  invalid source encoding name "UTF16"
********** Error **********
```

Comment: Thank you guys, both techniques works fine.  A function seems to be more accurate than using Unicode escaped sequences. For my application, accuracy is not required, so both techniques would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's right, Postgres doesn't support UTF-16.

However, it does support [Unicode escape sequences](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-UESCAPE):

```
SELECT U&'\0633\0644\0627\0645'
```

But keep in mind that **Unicode code points** and **UTF-16 code units** are only equivalent in the [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane). In other words, if you have any UTF-16 characters which span multiple 16-bit code units, you'll need to translate them to the corresponding code point yourself.

Answer (score 5):

PostgreSQL does not support UTF-16 natively. I suggest you to convert your data to UTF-8 before supplying it to the DB. If it's too late (wrong data already exists in your DB), you can use these maintenance functions to convert data from UTF-16 (logic copied from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Example_code)):

```
-- convert from bytea, containing UTF-16-BE data
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION convert_from_utf16be(utf16_data bytea, invalid_replacement text DEFAULT '?')
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql
  IMMUTABLE
  STRICT
AS $function$
WITH source(unit) AS (
  SELECT (get_byte(utf16_data, i) << 8) | get_byte(utf16_data, i + 1)
  FROM generate_series(0, octet_length(utf16_data) - 2, 2) i
),
codes(lag, unit, lead) AS (
  SELECT lag(unit, 1) OVER (), unit, lead(unit, 1) OVER ()
  FROM source
)
SELECT string_agg(CASE
  WHEN unit >= 56320 AND unit <= 57343 THEN CASE
    WHEN lag >= 55296 AND lag <= 56319 THEN '' -- already processed
    ELSE invalid_replacement
  END
  WHEN unit >= 55296 AND unit <= 56319 THEN CASE
    WHEN lead >= 56320 AND lead <= 57343 THEN chr((unit << 10) + lead - 56613888)
    ELSE invalid_replacement
  END
  ELSE chr(unit)
END, '')
FROM codes
$function$;

-- convert from bytea, containing UTF-16-LE data
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION convert_from_utf16le(utf16_data bytea, invalid_replacement text DEFAULT '?')
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql
  IMMUTABLE
  STRICT
AS $function$
WITH source(unit) AS (
  SELECT get_byte(utf16_data, i) | (get_byte(utf16_data, i + 1) << 8)
  FROM generate_series(0, octet_length(utf16_data) - 2, 2) i
),
codes(lag, unit, lead) AS (
  SELECT lag(unit, 1) OVER (), unit, lead(unit, 1) OVER ()
  FROM source
)
SELECT string_agg(CASE
  WHEN unit >= 56320 AND unit <= 57343 THEN CASE
    WHEN lag >= 55296 AND lag <= 56319 THEN '' -- already processed
    ELSE invalid_replacement
  END
  WHEN unit >= 55296 AND unit <= 56319 THEN CASE
    WHEN lead >= 56320 AND lead <= 57343 THEN chr((unit << 10) + lead - 56613888)
    ELSE invalid_replacement
  END
  ELSE chr(unit)
END, '')
FROM codes
$function$;

-- convert from bytea, containing UTF-16 data (with or without BOM)
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION convert_from_utf16(utf16_data bytea, invalid_replacement text DEFAULT '?')
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql
  IMMUTABLE
  STRICT
AS $function$
SELECT CASE COALESCE(octet_length(utf16_data), 0)
  WHEN 0 THEN ''
  WHEN 1 THEN invalid_replacement
  ELSE CASE substring(utf16_data FOR 2)
    WHEN E'\\xFFFE' THEN convert_from_utf16le(substring(utf16_data FROM 3), invalid_replacement)
    ELSE convert_from_utf16be(substring(utf16_data FROM 3), invalid_replacement)
  END
END
$function$;
```

With these functions, you can convert from all kind of UTF-16:

```
SELECT convert_from_utf16be(decode('0633064406270645D852DF62', 'hex')),
       convert_from_utf16le(decode('330644062706450652D862DF', 'hex')),
       convert_from_utf16(decode('FEFF0633064406270645D852DF62', 'hex')),
       convert_from_utf16(decode('FFFE330644062706450652D862DF', 'hex'));

-- convert_from_utf16be | convert_from_utf16le | convert_from_utf16 | convert_from_utf16
------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+-------------------
-- سلام                | سلام                | سلام              | سلام
```

Answer (score 3):

`convert_from` (or PostgreSQL in general) doesn't support `UTF-16`, but you may resort to one of the optional languages that do.

Example in `plperlu` (requires database superuser privileges to create the function, and `CREATE LANGUAGE plperlu` if not created already):

```
CREATE FUNCTION decode_utf16(text) RETURNS text AS $$
  require Encode;
  return Encode::decode("UTF-16BE", pack("H*", $_[0]));
$$ immutable language plperlu;

=> select decode_utf16('0633064406270645');

 decode_utf16 
--------------
 سلام
```